# how can I group my variables in just one row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store all the file’s name in just one row after upload them

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$name = $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"][$key];
$ext = substr(strrchr($name, '.'), 1);
```

when I echo this variable

```
$thelist .= $name.',';
echo $thelist
```

result. image1,image2,image3,

but in Mysql table the result is each one in diferent row and col.

```
image1,,,
image1,image2,
image1,image2,image3,
```

I just need all in one row in one col. like

```
image1,image2,image3,
```

Comment: *"but in Mysql table the result is each one in diferent row and col."* - Since you're using this for SQL, I noticed `$key`. You wouldn't be using `key` as a column by any chance, are you? (it's a reserved word); just an insight. You should show us what you're using for SQL code, problem might be in there.

Comment: Also add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: are you looping over the insert query ?

Comment: Why do you think you need comma-separated values in your column?  9 times out of 19, when someone takes this approach, it is a poor choice versus proper normalization of the data.